# Java: having an issue with serialization over a LAN network

Tags: java, networking, ioexception

Sorry if this is a repost of another question; I couldn't find anything after an hour of googling. Anyways, here's the issue: I have a server class and a client class in a game. The server should be sending an object over the network to the client which contains all of the information. However, when I try to send it, it gives me an IO.EOFException. Here's the code for everything:

```
public class NetworkClient {
private static Socket socket = null;
private static ObjectOutputStream oos;
private static ObjectInputStream ois;
private static FileInputStream fileIn;

public static void startConnection(){
    try {
        socket = new Socket("192.168.1.5", 4445);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Don't know about host.");
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for "
                           + "the connection to: 192.168.1.5.");

    }
    fileIn = null;
}

public static void getVariables(){
    try
    {
       FileInputStream fileIn =
                     new FileInputStream("variables.ser");
       ois = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
       Display.variables = (Variables) ois.readObject();
       ois.close();
       fileIn.close();
   }catch(IOException i)
   {
       i.printStackTrace();
       return;
   }catch(ClassNotFoundException c)
   {
       System.out.println("Variables class not found");
       c.printStackTrace();
       return;
 }
 }
 }
```

And here's the server:

```
public class NetworkHost {
    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private static Socket clientSocket;
    private static ObjectInputStream ois;
    private static ObjectOutputStream oos;

public static void startConnection(){

            serverSocket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4445);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 4444.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
            clientSocket = null;
        try {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Accept failed.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        try {
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}

public static void sendVariables(){
    try
      {
         FileOutputStream fileOut =
         new FileOutputStream("variables.ser");
         ObjectOutputStream out =
                            new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
         out.writeObject(Display.variables);
         out.close();
          fileOut.close();
      }catch(IOException i)
      {
          i.printStackTrace();
      }
}   
}
```

And finally, here is the error:

```
  java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2280)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2749)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:779)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:279)
    at com.dodger.NetworkClient.getVariables(NetworkClient.java:36)
at com.dodger.Display.main(Display.java:129)
```

So really, long story short, I screwed something stupid up (probably) and now the object won't send between the client and the server. Any ideas for fixes? Thanks!

Comment: There is no exception message?

Comment: @skynorth By exception message do you mean the error I included at the bottom?

Comment: Does your class implement Serializable?

Comment: It is weird. I usually get stack traces with error messages, like this: `java.sql.SQLException: Illegal operation on empty result set.`

Comment: @skynorth Maybe it's because I'm just printing stack trace?

Comment: @Wug, yea, pretty much. From what I've gathered through my internet searching, I'm pretty much making the object into a file and sending it to the client to be made back into an object.

Comment: I misread it a bit.  It doesn't look like you ever send anything to the client from the server.

Comment: yeah.  sendVariables is writing to a file, and unless you are reading that file somewhere else and sending it to the client, the client is never getting anything.

Comment: @Wug Oh... What would I add to fix this? I'm assuming it's just something to make the ObjectOutPutStream send the file to the client instead?

Comment: There's no need for a file here - the server should write directly to the socket's output stream, not to a file. See Wug's answer for an illustration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like your server is actually sending anything to the client.  Unless there is something else outside of the shown code, `Display.variables` is never being sent to the network.

Consider this approach for the client:

```
private static Socket socket = null;
private static ObjectOutputStream oos;
private static ObjectInputStream ois;

// snip ...

public static void getVariables()
{
    try
    {
       ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
       Display.variables = (Variables) ois.readObject();
       ois.close();
    }
    catch(IOException i)
    {
       i.printStackTrace();
       return;
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException c)
    {
       System.out.println("Variables class not found");
       c.printStackTrace();
       return;
    }
}
```

And this approach for the server:

```
private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
private static Socket clientSocket;
private static ObjectInputStream ois;
private static ObjectOutputStream oos;

// snip ...

public static void sendVariables()
{
    try
    {
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        out.writeObject(Display.variables);
        out.close();
    }
    catch(IOException i)
    {
        i.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I'm not 100% sure this will work for you exactly as written, it depends on how you do your initialization, and where.  Consider this a guideline.

Also your indentation is atrocious.

Comment: Yea, sorry about that. I'm not the best at organization. I figure it'll come after I figure out what I'm doing. Also, I'll try fixing this up. As of now, it's giving me an error saying the socket is closed...

Comment: Did you forget to open it?  Also if youre using eclipse, type ctrl+shift+f to format.  fixes indentation and whatever

Comment: @Mordecai maybe you should try working though some socket tutorials before throwing ObjectInputStream into the mix. This is a good start: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html

Comment: @Wug No, the game waits until the socket is opened to start playing. And Alex, I think I do need more tutorials on this... I didn't realize networking would be such a pain.

Comment: There are far too many problems with this code. The socket and stream members shouldn't be static; the streams shouldn't be recreated for each method invocation; closing the output stream closes the socket. This will never work. Downvote.

Comment: @EJP Hm... If you feel that way, could you provide another example? I feel like he was on the right track. I'm very new to networking, but he seemed pretty close. Oh, and the code still doesn't run. I think I just need to fix one or two more things.

Answer (score 1):

I can't make any sense of this.

1. Your title says 'serialization over a LAN network' but the code you say doesn't work reads from a file.
2. Your server writes to a file; your client reads from a file. What therefore is the socket actually for? And if the server and client aren't on the same machine, how is this possibly going to work?
3. `EOFException` when reading `ObjectInputStream` just means you have reached the end of the stream: the peer has closed the connection and there are no more objects.
4. Unless your server is designed to only service one client, the clientSocket and stream variables must not be static, and they must be in a different class that is instantiated per connection, typically a Runnable, that manages the connection and that is started in its own thread.

Comment: Yeah, the more I'm looking at the original code, the more I'm starting to wonder where I thought of it. It does pretty much nothing. Really all I want is a client class and a host class. The host should be able to send a class to the client every game loop. I'm able to establish a connection to the other computer, and Wug's code looks closer to what I'm searching for. Now that I'm looking at it, that original code I made is getting more and more disgraceful by the second.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the client is trying to read the file that's still empty. How are you running this app? Where is the main method? It's not a serialization issue.

Comment: At the end of each loop in the actual part, I have this:    if(multiStatus == 1)
    networkHost.sendVariables();
   if(multiStatus == 2)
    networkClient.getVariables();
That sends the variables and receives them. I think.